# Not getting Value of concatenated string in html checkbox value using jsp

Tags: database, string, jsp, dynamic

I am trying to set the value of checkbox as a string but the complete string value is not going in database. 
here is my code.

```
        <div align="center">
        <%
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();                            
            String time1 = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":00" + " - " + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":15";
            String time2 = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":16" + " - " + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":30";
            String time3 = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":31" + " - " + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":45";
            String time4 = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":46" + " - " + Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":59"; 
        %>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                    <%
                        out.print(time1);
                    %>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="time" id="time1" value=<%=time1%> />
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>   

                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                    <%
                        out.print(time2);
                    %>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="time" id="time2" value=<%=time2%> />
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>   

                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                    <%
                        out.print(time3);
                    %>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="time" id="time3" value=<%=time3%> />
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>   

                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                    <%
                        out.print(time4);
                    %>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="time" id="time4" value=<%=time4%> />
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>   

                <tr> <td colspan = 2>&nbsp; </td> </tr>   

                <tr> 
                    <td colspan = 2 align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" width="148" height="43" title="Click to submit monitoring time slot"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
            </table>
        </div>
```

When i am printing the value of time strings value is correct but not in database.

check screenshots.
![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Since you are using checkbox, you will not checkbox value from submitted data. You will get the data of "name" as either **on/off**. Also you were using the same property (name) for all checkboxes. post your servlet code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, i forgot to use "" for value.

Example `value = "<%=time1>"`